# How to write this from javascript to JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, simplemodal

Simple question I need these few lines of javascript in jquery.
Just trying to close a modal when I select outside of it.

Thank you.

```
 // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
 if (event.target == myModal) {
    myModal.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more info

Comment: When you select "outside of it"? The code you show seems to do the opposite of that, i.e., close when you click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the modal is being clicked "myModal" ... so ...

```
$("#myModal").on("click",function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: This worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will click on body and and check if the target is modal with Id myModal

```
$('body').on('click',function(event){
  var getTargetId = event.target.id;
  if(getTargetId== myModal){
     $(this).attr('display', 'none')
   }
})
```

Assuming you will click on the modal with id myModal

```
$("#myModal").on("click",function() {
    $(this).attr('display', 'none');
});
```